# Convert data in character format to readable table

Tags: r

I have got a data set from a website using `GET function` and `httr` package, however the data is now in character format as below. How do I convert it into table so I can plot? Thanks a lot!

```
print(resContent)

[1] "{\"pTType\":\"line\",\"gBType\":\"line\",\"data\":[[9624,8873,8671,8420,8452,8718,9712,10373,11061,11708,11253,10482,10780,10829,10884,11318,10849,10732],[1635,1244,1361,1493,1695,1478,1838,1787,1824,1985,1983,1802,2030,2253,2251,2127,1972,2023]]}"

> length(resContent)
[1] 1

> typeof(resContent)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: This looks like json formatted data. I would do a search f or converting json to dataframe.

Comment: better use `dput` to show data( show `dput(resContent)`)

Comment: do you need all the values to plot as histogram

Comment: I want to plot the data into line chart with multiple lines , each dataset is presented as one line

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption that the names of the first two elements were the names of the columns, but I'm not sure that's a solid assumption.  Regardless, the code below should get you moving in the right direction.

```
library(rjson)
library(magrittr)
resContent <- "{\"pTType\":\"line\",\"gBType\":\"line\",\"data\":[[9624,8873,8671,8420,8452,8718,9712,10373,11061,11708,11253,10482,10780,10829,10884,11318,10849,10732],[1635,1244,1361,1493,1695,1478,1838,1787,1824,1985,1983,1802,2030,2253,2251,2127,1972,2023]]}"

rjson::fromJSON(resContent)$data %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("PTType", "gBType"))
```

Comment: thank you very much! this gives me exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

The following will extract the comma separated numbers from the string that you have provided and return a numeric vector:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("^.*\\[(\\d.*)\\]\\].*$", "\\1", resContent), split=",")))

[1] 1635 1244 1361 1493 1695 1478 1838 1787 1824 1985 1983 1802 2030 2253 2251 2127 1972 2023
```

- `gsub` extracts the subexpression (substring of comma separated numbers),
- `strsplit` splits this on the commas,
- `unlist` returns a vector of the numbers stored as characters
- `as.numeric` converts these into a numeric vector.